# What if i import modules inside the constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

Is requiring modules inside constructor a bad practice? I am trying to achieve dynamic module reloading.

```
class Product {

    constructor() {
        this.product = require('../db/models/_product');
        this.helpers = require('./index');
    }

    getProducts(qty) {
        return this.product.find().limit(qty);
    }

    findProduct(product_id) {
        return this.product.findById(product_id);
    }

    searchProduct(searchTerm) {
        return this.product.find({$text: {$search: searchTerm, $caseSensitive: false}});
    }
}
```

Comment: You can, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Since your class doesn't hold any state and not even any data but the static(!) module exports, you should not even be using a `class` at all. Just write your module that exports the three functions. Don't use any constructor.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad practice. Imports should go to the top of the code as it improves readability and allows for static code analysis.